# HTTP Video Streaming Codec for iOS and Android (HTML5 embedding)

Tags: android, ios, html, video, codec

can anybody tell me the best HTML5 embedding code and video-codec (+file format) for streaming video-content over the internet (HTTP-Streaming)??
The videos should be watched without problems on iOS (iPhone + iPad) and Android phones!

thanks!
Mike

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html

that page goes into detail about using html5 video and appropriate codecs for different browsers, including iOS and android.

Comment: It doesn't talk about STREAMING though, which was the point of the question. These are all for on-demand videos...

Answer (score 0):

Until DASH becomes widely supported, streaming video into HTML5 on mobile devices is extremely limited.

The only option at this moment is to use Apple's HLS, which works wonderfully on iPhone/iPad/iPod, but doesn't work in Android. https://developer.apple.com/streaming/

Google's WebM is being worked on, and there's some stuff here: https://sites.google.com/a/webmproject.org/wiki/adaptive-streaming/instructions-to-playback-a-webm-dash-presentation , but I haven't tried it on Android.